# Inverter "string"

Tags: c, string

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
void InverterString(char *str1){
    char aux[strlen(str1)];   

   for (int c=0; c<5; c++) aux[c] = str1[4 - c];

    printf("A string1 invertida fica: %s", aux);
}
```

Porém, ele imprime a frase que está no `printf`, mas não imprime a string. Por quê?

Obrigada.

Answer (score 1):

Para mim, `InverterString("abcde");` produziu como resposta `edcba`. [**Veja aqui no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/KZIUM8)

No entanto, devido aos números 5 e 4 chapados no código, isso só funciona para strings de tamanho 5. Quaisquer strings maiores ou menores, isso vai dar errado. Para resolver isso, você já tem o `strlen`, então é só usá-lo para achar o tamanho adequado da string. Basta substituir `5` pelo tamanho da string e `4` pelo tamanho da string menos 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void InverterString(char *str1) {
    int tamanho = strlen(str1);
    char aux[tamanho + 1];

    for (int c = 0; c < tamanho; c++) {
        aux[c] = str1[tamanho - c - 1];
    }
    aux[tamanho] = 0;

    printf("A string1 invertida fica: %s", aux);
}

int main(void) {
    InverterString("O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma e a rainha roeu o resto.");
    return 0;
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
A string1 invertida fica: .otser o ueor ahniar a e amoR ed ier od apuor a ueor otar O
```

Ah, e observe que é necessário colocar o terminador nulo (0) explicitamente também no `aux`.

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/76GlcO)

Answer (score 0):

Fica mais elegante e funcional que você crie uma variável e atribua à ela o valor do **tamanho** da sua string de entrada, assim funcionará para qualquer tamanho de string. 
Além disso, tentando modificar minimamente o seu código, fiz a alteração e incluí a biblioteca **string.h** e ficou assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void InverterString(char *str1){
    int tamanho=strlen(str1);
    char aux[tamanho];   

    for (int c=0; c<tamanho; c++) aux[c] = str1[(tamanho-1)-c];

    printf("A string1 invertida fica: %s", aux);
}

int main(void) {
    InverterString("Olá Danny!");
    return 0;
}
```